# What overhead in using HttpContext.Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some code as follows

```
var MyObjectInstance =  httpContext.Items[key] as MyObject
```

What overhead is there in this code. Does it need to deserialize the object as well as doing a cast. Is there any significant performance benefit in reducing the number of these calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpContext.Items` really returns a `HashTable` (in-memory dictionary) - so call such as `httpContext.Items[key] as MyObject` will essentially has to

1. Look up within dictionary for the said key
2. Cast the object

There is no deserialization

Performance Benefit will be a relative term - how many times such calls are made? This would be a very fast call, unless you are making thousands of calls in a short time-frame, I would not worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Interesting. It is getting called several times for each request for a very high volume site. I'm just considering some refactoring that would ensure it would only be called once per request. Just trying to decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: @Mark909, it depends from where it is getting called? For example, if page code calls it repeatedly, you can cache the value in a variable. User controls can access it from page. You need to take decision by comparing your average request response time with the time for this call (which I believe will in range of few micro-seconds).

Comment: It's getting called from a Castle instantiated object on a PerWebRequest so I can store this as variable in this object rather than read it out of httpContext each time.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Items (IDictionary) collection is very useful especially if we want to stored object on the server-side. Take a look at some interesting articles - [3 hot uses for HttpContext.Current.Items they wont tell you about.](http://www.mikeduncan.com/3-hot-uses-for-httpcontextcurrentitems-they-wont-tell-you-about/) and [When can we use HttpContext.Current.Items to stores data in ASP.NET?](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/14/when-we-can-use-httpcontext-current-items-to-stores-data-in-asp-net/)

Answer (score -2):

HttpContext is very large and thus should be avoided. On a side note it is sealed, and thus cannot be unit tested and mocked.

```
 var MyObjectInstance = httpContext.Items[key] = new MyObject();
```

Items is a hashtable object holding key and value pairs, thus relatively fast.

This article may help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx